# ListView Item Position Change on Scroll

Tags: android, listview

When I scroll down/up so quickly, the position changes so fast that it messes up the item for the position, causing the texts to change instead of what it should be. I've been searched around fixes but can't seem to figure where it went wrong. Below is my Custom ArrayAdapter Code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import aungkyawpaing.ngapyinkeyboard.Models.CustomKey;
import aungkyawpaing.ngapyinkeyboard.R;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

/**
 * Created by Vincent on 16-Apr-15.
 */
public class CustomKeyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomKey> {

    private int size;
    ArrayList<CustomKey> datas = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomKeyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomKey> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem_customkey, list);
        size = list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView != null) {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } else {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_customkey, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        CustomKey key = getItem(position);
        datas.add(position, key);

        viewHolder.txt_number.setText("Key #" + (position + 1) + " : ");
        viewHolder.value_field.setText(key.getOutput());
        viewHolder.value_field.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private int position;

        public MyTextWatcher(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            CustomKey key = getItem(position);
            key.setOutput(editable.toString());
            datas.add(position, key);
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        @InjectView(R.id.custom_key_number) TextView txt_number;
        @InjectView(R.id.custom_key_value) EditText value_field;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<CustomKey> getValues() {
        return datas;
    }
}
```

EDIT: TextView is fine, it's just the texts in EditText that keep changing

Comment: (https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+listview+scrolling+issue&oq=android+listview+scrolling+issue&aqs=chrome..69i57.9863j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)[link]..

Comment: I have googled before asking. :) most of the answer tell to change the pattern of viewholder which is exactly the same as my pattern

Comment: You have to use separate class for ViewHolder. That holder should be private. The same issue I faced and solved..!! [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486148/how-to-solve-scroll-issue-in-gridview-in-android) ..

Comment: @NewDeveloper I can't use private while using ButterKnife. I'll try changing it to normal way without ButterKnife

Answer (score 1):

Before adding the `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` remove the existing `TextWatcher` of the `EditText`.
In the `TextWatcher`

```
 static class ViewHolder {
        @InjectView(R.id.custom_key_number) TextView txt_number;
        @InjectView(R.id.custom_key_value) EditText value_field;
        MyTextWatcher myWatcher;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        }
    }
```

Now remove the existing `TextWatcher` of the `EditText`,initialize the `TextWatcher` of the view holder in the `getView()` method and add the `TextWatcher` to the EditText

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView != null) {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } else {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_customkey, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        CustomKey key = getItem(position);
        datas.add(position, key);

        viewHolder.txt_number.setText("Key #" + (position + 1) + " : ");
        viewHolder.value_field.setText(key.getOutput());
        //Remove the myWatcher
        viewHolder.value_field.emoveTextChangedListener(myWatcher);
        viewHolder.myWatcher=new MyTextWatcher(position);
        //add the myWatcher
        viewHolder.value_field.addTextChangedListener(myWatcher);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Still changing on scroll but thanks. watcher should be implemented should have been this way

Comment: you have maintained a List<CustomKey> called datas, what is the use of it?

Comment: getValues is called by the activity which has this layout and save those values from the edittext into the database. It's called when the user click the save menu options. datas is used to store these custom keys

Comment: Instead of saving the data in the List<CustomKey> it is better to user HashMap<int,CustomKey> for storing the data because HashMap will be automatically update if item at the position already exists

Comment: I have solved the issue. I will Seems like in "onTextChanged", the key is referencing to the item in the view. and therefore setOutput changes that key output. Fixed the issue and reading tutorial on HashMap now :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. I will Seems like in "onTextChanged", the key is referencing to the item in the view. and therefore setOutput changes that key output. Fixed the issue with following code

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    CustomKey key = getItem(position);
    datas.add(position,  new CustomKey(key.getCode(), editable.toString()));
}
```